# rsconnect (& PKI installation) failure

Tags: pki, shinyapps, rsconnect

im trying to install rsconnect to connect to shinyapps.io for online hosting. This is my first app so bear with me.

while installing rsconnect through:

```
install.packages("rsconnect")
```

it runs through the installation with the checks etc:

```
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking openssl/ssl.h usability... yes
checking openssl/ssl.h presence... no
configure: WARNING: openssl/ssl.h: accepted by the compiler, rejected by the preprocessor!
configure: WARNING: openssl/ssl.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
checking for openssl/ssl.h... yes
checking openssl/rsa.h usability... yes
checking openssl/rsa.h presence... no
configure: WARNING: openssl/rsa.h: accepted by the compiler, rejected by the preprocessor!
configure: WARNING: openssl/rsa.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
checking for openssl/rsa.h... yes
checking for library containing RSA_generate_key_ex... no
configure: error: Cannot find usable crypto library
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘PKI’
* removing ‘/cnN0dWRpby1yYWNoYW5kR/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/PKI’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘PKI’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘PKI’ is not available for package ‘rsconnect’
* removing ‘/cnN0dWRpby1yYWNoYW5k/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/rsconnect’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rsconnect’ had non-zero exit status
```

A dependancy on PKI seems to be killing this installation. Installation of PKI separately though

```
install.packages("PKI")
```

also fails with the warning

```
configure: error: Cannot find usable crypto library
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘PKI’
```

I am running on an enterprise VM that i do not have normal access to, but can only use apps installed therein. I do not have access to the VM terminal either unfortunately.